# how to fake signalr call in a backend-less angularjs app

Tags: angularjs, signalr

I am currently developing an angularjs app where I am using the $httpBackend service to fake the rest api calls.

I have been looking for a way to fake signalr hub calls but I haven't found anything about the subject so far.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what do you mean by fake ?

Comment: I want to do exactly what I am doing with httpBackend for the api calls. I want to simulate that a hub connection have been open and fake the hub methods behavior even when they haven't been implemented yet